# How to set refresh token expire of drf social oauth2?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-socialauth

How can we set refresh token expire of drf social oauth2.

I try to use this but not work(Work only access token).

`OAUTH2_PROVIDER = { 'REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRE_SECONDS': 1,  #set to 1 second for test 'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKEN': false, }`

Anyone can help?